# Re: process.env.PORT || '3000' is underlined in red

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am following the "MySQL Node Express API - Walkthrough" on YouTube and have the following error and don't know how to solve it.
Not sure if I haven't added an extension that is needed and this is also my first app that I am trying to make.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZHhW.jpg)

How do I correct this error I have seemed to have made?

Regards,
Kyle

Comment: `${}` is template literals check this [Click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and don't use string in port number use only numbers.

Comment: Please paste code into the question instead of an image.

Comment: Thank-you turivishal

Comment: Sorry Zera, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). However, a template literal requires backticks (`` ` ``) and you are attempting to use single quotes (`'`).

The `console.log()` should look like the following:

```js
console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || '3000'}`);
```